# Android - XMPP asmack PacketListener throws CalledFromWrongThreadException hierarchy view

Tags: android, multithreading, xmpp, smack, asmack

I´ve build a little XMPP Application on Android with asmack 4.0.5. I want to implement the presence status of the chat-partner. I can get the information with logging-function in Eclipse, but I cannot show/update it on the Chatting-UI. I have got 2 Listener: The `PacketListener` which is doing good with incoming messages and the `RosterListener` which is able to receive the presence status, but not able to show it on the UI. The `PacketListener` is build this way:

```
PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                            .getFrom());
                    messages.add(message.getBody());
                    listMessage.add(new MessageData(message.getBody()));                        
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                        public void run() {
 //listview = chatmessages which are updated every time I receive a message
                                listview.invalidateViews();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }, filter);
```

And then I have got my `RosterListener`:

```
final Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
    @Override
    public void presenceChanged(final Presence presence) {
        presenceUser = presence.getFrom();
        Presence availability = roster.getPresence(presenceUser);
        Mode userMode = availability.getMode();
        availableMode.setText(getPresenceStatus(...)); // Here is where a TextView 'availableMode' should be updated, but I get the Error shown below.
    }

    @Override
    public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
    }
});
```

Every time my RosterListener wants to update the UI, I get the following Exception:

```
   E/XMPPConnection(1314): Exception in packet listener
   E/XMPPConnection(1314):android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

How can I can independently update the UI with incoming presence information from my RosterListener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `availableMode.setText(getPresenceStatus(...));` in a runnable and then use `post(…)` to have the UI update take place on the UI thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)

> View#post Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue. The runnable will be run on the user interface thread.

`availableMode.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            availableMode.setText(getPresenceStatus(...));
        }
    });`